Can't able to login google auth in telegram mini apps
I'm developing a Telegram mini app, but I'm facing an issue while trying to log in with Google. In my app, I implemented the Google OAuth method.


The next app with Google auth login works locally and in ngrok. But not working on telegram mini apps.
It returns We're sorry, but you do not have access to this page. That’s all we know.


Please edit to provide a [mcve] with all relevant detail. Right now there's no specifics, just a screenshot and part of an error message.
